# Let $G$ be a group. Show that if the left coset gH is a subgroup of $G$, then g is in $H$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. Show that if the left coset $gH$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $g \in H$.

### My attempt

Assume $gH \leq G$.

Then there exists the identity element $e$ of $gH$ such that $eh=h \in gH,  \forall h\in H$.

Now, let $x, y \in gH$ such that there exists $h_1, h_2 \in H$ and $g_1, g_2 \in G$ satisfying $x = g_1 h_1, y = g_2 h_2$.

Note also that $y^{-1} = h_2^{-1} g_2^{-1}$.

Now: $$x y^{-1} = g_1 h_1 h_2^{-1} g_2^{-1} \tag{*}$$

There exists $h'\in H$ such that $h' = h_1 h_2^{-1}$.

So, $(*)$ becomes $x y^{-1} = g_1 h' g_2^{-1}$

Now how do I show that $g_1 h' g_2^{-1} \in gH$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $gH \le G$, then $e \in gH$, then by definition of $gH$ we can find $h$ such that $gh=e$, whence $g=h^{-1}$, whence $g \in H$.

Comment: A lot easier :)